# Woocommerce Short Description Excerpt Length

Tags: php, wordpress, filter, woocommerce

I'm trying to change the Short Description excerpt length.

I found a previous post stating that I should change

```
<?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', $post->post_excerpt ) ?>
```

to

```
<?php $excerpt = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', $post->post_excerpt );
    echo substr($length,0, 10);
?>
```

However when doing that, my excerpts simply disappear.

Comment: look carefully at the name of your variable where you store your excerpt and at the first param of `substr`. See some difference? :P

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm afraid you're editing the plugin... if that's so, you're doing it wrong..

create a function and then hook to that filter... something like this...

```
add_filter('woocommerce_short_description', 'reigel_woocommerce_short_description', 10, 1);
function reigel_woocommerce_short_description($post_excerpt){
    if (!is_product()) {
        $post_excerpt = substr($post_excerpt, 0, 10);
    }
    return $post_excerpt;
}
```

paste this on your functions.php file of your theme.

Comment: <?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', $post->post_excerpt ); ?> is in "content-product.php", which is located in my theme.

I'm afraid that this function created the same issue and my excerpts disappeared.

Comment: That's right, the content hasn't been changed, yet this function isn't working and is left with the original <?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', $post->post_excerpt ); ?>.

Comment: if you remove that line of code ,`<?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', $post->post_excerpt ); ?>`, will the excerpt display still?

Comment: Ahh I made a typo on my code.. try and copy my updated code... again without editing `product.php`

Comment: Excellent! That worked! Thank you! Would happen to know how I could limit that function to archive pages and not the product page?

Comment: Saved my day! THANK YOU

Answer (score 2):

Instead of editing files directly within the plugin (which is a very bad idea because once update the plugin and all of your changes will be lost!)

You can use this code for **limit no of words** -

```
add_filter('woocommerce_short_description', 'limit_woocommerce_short_description', 10, 1);
    function limit_woocommerce_short_description($post_excerpt){
        if (!is_product()) {
            $pieces = explode(" ", $post_excerpt);
            $post_excerpt = implode(" ", array_splice($pieces, 0, 20));

        }
        return $post_excerpt;
    }
```

**explode** breaks the original string into an array of words, array_splice lets you get certain ranges of those words, and then **implode** combines the ranges back together into single strings.

**use this code to change Limit on the Shop Page not Product-detailed Page**.

Comment: Is there any way to place ... (three comas) in the end of the excerpt to indicate that it is not fully quoted but rather cut off? Thank you.